# How do I start mvn test phase on Xvfb?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, junit, xvfb

I made some unit-tests using [fest](http://code.google.com/p/fest/), now I need to run mvn my test using maven on a headless system. I would like to run test using Xvfb but I need help to configure maven to start Xvfb before testing and stop it when all is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I use this plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-xvfb</id>
            <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <echo message="Starting xvfb ..." />
                    <exec executable="Xvfb" spawn="true">
                        <arg value=":1" />
                    </exec>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>shutdown-xvfb</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <echo message="Ending xvfb ..." />
                    <exec executable="killall">
                            <arg value="Xvfb" />
                    </exec>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The good is that you get a background process (with `spawn = "true"`) and you can kill the Xvfb process (with `killall`) without having to write any script. Moreover in my Ubuntu distro I don't hav to set any special setting in my sudoers file to let this works.

The shutdown-xvfb execution is executed at the end of the test phase but (here is the problem) is not executed if the test fail. This is not a problem if you want to restart another test (the old Xvfb is still running and the new one can't run, but  this is not a problem) but the problem is that the resources are still busy by Xvfb. A workaround for this could be to add `testFailureIgnore = "true"` to the configuration of maven-surefire-plugin but this way I can't easily see if some test fail.

Comment: That works too. Curious, why don't you just add `<exec executable="killall"><arg value="Xvfb" /></exec>` before starting `Xvfb` in your `start-xvfb` execution? Or are you mostly concerned about *not* leaving Xvfb running for another (boy-scout-campsite) reason? Alternatively using a CI environment like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) it's trivial to trigger other builds on failures (ie. a "Stop Xvfb" build).

Comment: @Anew I simply don't add the killall before starting because in my environment I don't have any errors (if there was another instance yet the second is simply not started) but I would like to stop it at the end to have always a clean environment (I use this pc even for other tasks). Thanks for the suggestion using [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) / [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) or other CI environment, I've programmed to setup such a thing as soon as I have time to learn how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

With the `exec-maven-plugin`:

You'll have to define two executions, one for starting your server and one for stopping it. You'll have to tie those execution configurations with the appropriate maven phase -- start the Xvfb before your test phase, and stop Xvfb after your test phase.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>exec-at-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase> <!-- runs right before 'test' -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>/home/anew/bin/manage-xvfb.sh</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>start</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>exec-at-prepare-package</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase> <!-- runs right after 'test' -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>/home/anew/bin/manage-xvfb.sh</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>stop</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Here is the content of the `manage-xvfb.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

XVFB_CMD="sudo /usr/bin/Xvfb :15 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x8"

function stop_xvfb {
  XVFB_PID=`ps ax | pgrep "Xvfb"`
  if [ "${XVFB_PID}" != "" ]; then
    sudo kill ${XVFB_PID}
  fi
}

if [ "${1}" == "start" ]; then
  stop_xvfb
  ${XVFB_CMD} &
elif [ "${1}" == "stop" ]; then
  stop_xvfb
fi
```

Note that you'll need to have `NOPASSWD` set in your sudoers file.

Comment: I have 2 problems here: 1st) executing Xvfb maven waits for process termination (we need a way to run it in background, probably running a shell script that call Xvfb :1 &); 2nd) the prepare-package phase isn't executed if some test fails so Xvfb keeps running.

Comment: 1) Create a shell script that a) checks if Xvfb is still running from a prior test run -- if it is, kill it. You'll need to do something like `kill \`ps axuf | pgrep Xvfb\`` to kill it. And b) Starts Xvfb if it isn't running with the `&` operator at the end of the line so that your shell script can exit but will leave Xvfb running asynchronously, like this: `/usr/X11R6/bin/Xvfb :15 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x8 &`

Comment: I've updated my example to show you what I mean. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This job can easily be done via the [selenium-maven-plugin](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.codehaus.mojo%7Cselenium-maven-plugin%7C2.3%7Cmaven-plugin):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>

  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>setup-xvfb</id>
      <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>xvfb</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Unfortunately, this plugin seems quite unmaintained. It was part of the [mojohaus project](http://www.mojohaus.org/) which recently migrated from `codehaus.org` to `github.com`. It seems no one has yet ported the `selenium-maven-plugin` to github and thus sources and documentation is currently not available on mojohaus' github page.

However, the JARs are available on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.codehaus.mojo%7Cselenium-maven-plugin%7C2.3%7Cmaven-plugin) and the plugin can still be used. There is a fork of the sources and site available on github [here](https://github.com/sonatype/selenium-maven-plugin), if you need to lookup some more configuration parameters.